# Embedded Power Bi report throws exception on Save, works the second time

Tags: powerbi-embedded

We have an integration with power bi service, whereby we're embedding a report within our site.

We are generated a token server side, with edit capability, and using that to display the report.

Clicking - File -> Save on the report has been working fine.

Now, clicking File -> Save results in the error below - one I have never seen before "Credential Handling Error". However clicking Save a second time works without any failure (and the changes are actually saved, as confirmed by viewing the report in PBI Service).

Has anyone else experienced this? We have not made any significant changes and also given that a second save works it seems like there is something wrong on the PBI side?

Any suggestions are welcome!

[image]

Comment: MS have responded that its a bug/issue on their end that they are resolving soon (hopefully)